# C++: How do I route file input stream to cout in one statement? inputStream >> cout doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

How do I take output from a stream and link directly into cout.

For example: inStream >> cout... This doesn't actually work through. PLZ HELP

Comment: Are you trying to write the content of an existing stream to `cout`? Or, are you trying to make it so that data written to a given stream will then write the data to `cout`? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

I think [`rdbuf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) helps you:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::istringstream input{ "Some content" };
    std::cout << input.rdbuf();
    std::ifstream file{ R"(b:\test.txt)" };
    std::cout << file.rdbuf();
}
```